# Remove silence from end of GarageBand track

Tags: garageband

I have just edited a song in GarageBand on OS X. At the end of the music I discovered that I have almost 5 minutes of silence at the end of the track after the music stops.

I know how that track initially got extended: I brought in other tracks that initially were long but extracted just short clips to insert into my project.  Now I have extra silence on the end of the track—i.e when the music ends the CD doesn't stop until it gets through that extra 5 minutes of silence.  In my situation I need to burn the CD directly from GarageBand and not iTunes.

Can anyone tell me how to delete the 5 minutes of extra silence on the end after my music track ends?

Comment: You can't just click the little triangle in the bar that counts measures and drag backwards until you get to actual recording? Are you asking about deleting that space in GarageBand or iTunes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a loop region at the top of the timeline in the yellow bar. When exporting from GarageBand, preference will go to this region for the bounds of the track.

Comment: I am sooooo grateful!!! It worked beautifully! Thank you George for helping me out!! Have a great day!